# How do grouped view filters in Drupal work?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I've created a new field (field_testtype) with the following options:

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Coffee
- Milk

I now want to seperate these terms into two groups:

- Food
- Drinks

So whenever someone picks "Food" he will see entries with Apple, Banana or Orange. I tried the following, but unfortunately this won't show any results at all.

[image: Operator "Ist eines von" means "Is one of"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've found the answer: There's nothing wrong with the settings above, grouped filters simply won't work in Drupal due to a bug. The following helped me to fix it:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1810148